# Multiple Trait construction error in Scala

Tags: scala, anonymous-class

could someone please help me understand the error here? I think I understand anonymous class construction with traits in Scala. However, when I try to apply more than one trait I get an error expecting ";" or essential end of statement. The same problem seems to apply if I declare a class this way as well (with multiple traits that require anonymous implementation lines of code ? Line Test 3 fails below. Thank you.

```
class TestTraits 

trait A {def x:Int}
trait B {def y:Int}



object TestTraits {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

     val test1 = new TestTraits with A {def x=22}  //OK

     val test2 = new TestTraits with B {def y=33} //OK

     val test3 = new TestTraits with A {def x=22} with B {def y=33} //Errors: - ';' expected but 'with' 


  }  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid:

```
val test3 = new TestTraits with A with B {def x=22; def y=33}
```

A class definition can only have one *body* and what you are declaring is an *anonymous* class.

Comment: Many thanks I was confusing this syntax with constructor arguments (each with their own params next to the name)!